# Is there any issue with MAP in codes in R

Tags: r

I have a large database and I am not able to produce them here. I have two data databases as follows.

```
df1 <- read.table(text="A1  B1  C1  D1  E1
1234Z   721 224 223 987L
224 321 224 331 987L
321 321 224 441 141
321 440 456Y    331 141
321 1234Q   456Y    441 321
218 221 456Y    12A 321
218 440 19  223 321
161 1234Q   19  12A 123Q
1234Z   123Q    77  11A 123Q", header=TRUE)

df2 <- read.table(text=" BCG1   BCG2    BCG3    BCG4    BCG5
1   11  13  18  24
4   9   13  19  24
5   9   13  20  22
5   10  14  19  22
5   6   14  20  23
3   8   14  17  23
3   10  12  18  23
2   6   12  17  21
1   7   15  16  21", header=TRUE)
```

Df1 are factors which are coded by df2. I have used the following code:

```
df3 <- do.call(cbind.fill, c(Map(function(x,y)
data.frame(col=x,col2=unique(y)),
lapply(df1,unique),split(df2, col(df2))))
names(df3)<-c(rbind(df1), paste0("Zo", seq_along((df1))))
```

I wan to get  the following table

```
A1     BCG1   B1      BCG2   C1      BCG3    D1      BCG4    E1      BCG5
1234Z  1      721     11     224     13      223     18      987L    24
224    4      321     9      456Y    14      331     19      141     22
321    5      221     8      19      12      441     20      321     23
218    3      440     10     77      15      12A     17      123Q    21
161    2      1234Q   6                      11A     16     
              123Q    7
```

I am open to other codes. Thanks for your help

Comment: This code is riddled with syntax errors, including `< -` instead of `<- ` (extra space) and unbalanced parentheses. If this is truly your code, then you have other problems. If not, please provide correct code.

Comment: What is `split(df2, col(df2))` supposed to be producing? For me, it's a 5-long list where the first has 9 rows and the other 4 are 0-row frames.

Comment: Thank you, I have corrected it. The code may not be efficient. Do you have any idea to get the table? in the table, duplicates will be removed.

Comment: (It looks like @MrFlick's edit actually added the `< -` errors. Shame shame.)

Comment: (@r2evans my sincere apologies)

Comment: Not a problem at all.

Comment: @MrFlick, it's happened to me several times ... often I catch it, not always. That's one reason that I think democratic (or more meritocratic?) editing/correcting of questions/content/answers can be a good thing ... you know, "Community" :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following.

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

df3 <- c(df1, df2) %>%
  `[`(c(matrix(names(.), nrow = 2, byrow = T))) %>%
  map(~ as.character(unique(.))) %>%
  map_dfc(`[`, 1:max(lengths(.))) %>%
  mutate_all(coalesce, "")

# # A tibble: 6 x 10
#   A1    BCG1  B1    BCG2  C1    BCG3  D1    BCG4  E1    BCG5 
#   <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>
# 1 1234Z 1     721   11    224   13    223   18    987L  24   
# 2 224   4     321   9     456Y  14    331   19    141   22   
# 3 321   5     440   10    19    12    441   20    321   23   
# 4 218   3     1234Q 6     77    15    12A   17    123Q  21   
# 5 161   2     221   8     ""    ""    11A   16    ""    ""   
# 6 ""    ""    123Q  7     ""    ""    ""    ""    ""    ""
```

The outcome `df3` is a `tbl` object and the empty character strings will be printed as `""` by default. If you don't want to see the quotes, there are two choices:

1. `as.data.frame(df3)`
2. `print.data.frame(df3)`

The former coerces `df3` from `tbl` to `data.frame` and the latter doesn't change the class of object.

The result will be

```
#      A1 BCG1    B1 BCG2   C1 BCG3  D1 BCG4   E1 BCG5
# 1 1234Z    1   721   11  224   13 223   18 987L   24
# 2   224    4   321    9 456Y   14 331   19  141   22
# 3   321    5   440   10   19   12 441   20  321   23
# 4   218    3 1234Q    6   77   15 12A   17 123Q   21
# 5   161    2   221    8           11A   16          
# 6             123Q    7
```

Comment: It's impossible to "remove" NA in a `data.frame` object because the length of each column must be equal. If you remove them, the outcome will be a `list`.

Comment: Not interested  in the list, sorry

Comment: Can we make it like my output?

Comment: Please check the edited answer. I misunderstood what you want at first. It seems that you don't care about the class of each column, so I change all columns to character. Accordingly, @Ben's method can be achieved. It's a useful opinion.

Comment: Thank you, Darren